# How to modify registered XML schema for XMLTYPE in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype

Initially i had an XML schema and created a table with reference to that XML schema.

Now i want to add one more attribute to the existing XML schema.

How to do that?

Comment: Isn't that what [`dbms_xmlschema.registerschema`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlsch.htm#ARPLS70076) is for?

Comment: I already registered an schema, now i want to add an attribute it it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to to drop the schema and re-register.

```
begin 
    DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA(
   'SCHEMA_URL',
   DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETE_CASCADE);
   commit;
end;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xmlsch.htm#i1007471